# getting error for user-theme extension by executing commands

Tags: gnome, tweak

this are some commands to install user-theme extension.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
```

[click this.this is screenshot of terminal when this commands get executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2gku.png)

Comment: copy paste terminal commands and output rather than posting a screen shot. Highlight text -> edit -> copy then paste here in a code box.

Comment: the ppa you added does not have a repo for artful.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a ppa for gnome extensions

Download them directly from [Gnome extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/)

In your case https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/

The install directly ;)

If you wish to use a ppa, you will have to contact the ppa maintainer if you have a problem.

Comment: I've done it but user-theme option is not added in gnome tweak tool.I'm using ubuntu 17.10.The version of gnome shell is 3.26.1.

Comment: That is a different problem. Should work right away, if not log out and back in. If it is still not working, you would have to file a bug report (user themes works here).

Comment: @Java_student It's working fine for me, although mine is not a fresh installation, I upgraded to Artful from Ubuntu GNOME 17.04. If Tweaks is not working you may try to manage your installed extensions from here: https://extensions.gnome.org/local/